# How to mail disable a non-existing public folder in Exchange Server

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, public-folders

The title speaks for itself. A public folder has been deleted but the email address corresponding to a child mail-enabled folder cannot be deleted...

These are the Aliases I want to remove:

```
    PS C:\Users\jfb> get-mailpublicfolder -Identity "bccp11-036"

    Alias                Identity
    -----                --------
    bccp11-036           matricis.local/Microsoft Exchange System Objects/Correspondance 81807753


    PS C:\Users\jfb> disable-mailpublicfolder -Identity "matricis.local/Microsoft Exchange 
System Objects/Correspondance 81807753"

    Disable-MailPublicFolder : No existing 'PublicFolder' matches the following Identity: 'matricis.local/Microsoft Exchange System Objects/Correspondance 81807753'
    At line:1 char:25
    + disable-mailpublicfolder <<<<  -Identity "matricis.local/Microsoft Exchange System Objects/Correspondance 81807753"
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [Disable-MailPublicFolder], MapiOperationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 826D5700,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.MapiTasks.DisableMailPublicFolder
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved the issue, to solve this, we have to go into Active Directory Users and Computers. Under View, select Advanced Features. Now, under the /Microsoft Exchange System Objects folder, manually delete the Correspondance 81807753 object.

To prevent this, you have to mail-disable the public folder before deleting it from the public folders.

Comment: I was just going to suggest that... glad you've found it on your own :-)